# Qt how to create a new xls file

Tags: qt, xls

everyone, is there any way to use Qt create a new xls file in windows?
I want to make a new xls file like test.xls and write values in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using [Active Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-index.html).

This allows to use Active X (OLE) to interact with Excel. But this requires to have Excel installed on the computer that will run your program.

For a complete example you can see: http://wiki.qt.io/Using_ActiveX_Object_in_Qt

Another solution, if you only need to fill the cells of a spreadsheet is to create a CSV file. This has the following advantages:

- Way faster than using Active X/OLE.
- Simpler code.
- Works on any computer/OS without having Excel installed.
- And a CSV file can be opened by any spreadsheet software.

But you will not be able to use Excel advanced features (graphs, text font, etc.).

Comment: Or use an excel file library. Has the same advantages as CSV, but outputs an excel file and might support additional features.